# search directories and only jpg/js and fetch in array

Tags: php, arrays, function

I am using a function to display all the files. But I am not sure how to get that in a variable with comma seperated and then fetch in array.
here is the function that i have used.

```
function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext1, $ext2, &$array) {
$globFiles = glob("$dir/*.$ext1");
$globFiles2 = glob("$dir/*.$ext2");
$globDirs  = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {
    recursiveGlob($dir, $ext1, $ext2);
}

foreach ($globFiles as $file) {
    // print "$file<br>"; // Replace '\n' with '<br />' if outputting to browser
    $array[] = $file;
}
foreach ($globFiles2 as $file) {
    // print "$file<br>"; // Replace '\n' with '<br />' if outputting to browser
    $array[] = $file;
}
}
$array = array ();
recursiveGlob('C:\wamp\www\scanner\scanner', 'png', 'js', $array);
```

It might be a silly question. But please help me.

Comment: `get all files in a variable` does not really make sense. Would you mind renaming?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like in the end you wants an array with every file you found, just replace

```
print $file;
```

By

```
$array[] = $file;
```

Then, send this array in your recursive function using references :

```
function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext1, $ext2, &$array)
```

And use it like :

```
$array = array ();
recursiveGlob('C:\wamp\www\scanner\scanner', 'png', 'js', $array);
// At this point, $array will be an array with every files you found.
```

Tell me if I got your problem right and if you need to order your array in path levels, not sure what you're looking for but it would result in a clearer array.

Another solution without references and returning an array :

```
function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext1, $ext2) {
$globFiles = glob("$dir/*.$ext1");
$globFiles2 = glob("$dir/*.$ext2");
$globDirs  = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
$array = array ();
$array_file = array ();
foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {
    $array = array_merge ($array, recursiveGlob($dir, $ext1, $ext2));
}

foreach ($globFiles as $file) {
// print "$file<br>"; // Replace '\n' with '<br />' if outputting to browser
    $array_file[] = $file;
}
$array = array_merge ($array, $array_file);
$array_file = array ();
foreach ($globFiles2 as $file) {
// print "$file<br>"; // Replace '\n' with '<br />' if outputting to browser
    $array_file[] = $file;
}
$array = array_merge ($array, $array_file);
return $array;
}
$results = recursiveGlob('C:\wamp\www\scanner\scanner', 'png', 'js');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i am getting warning :  Warning: Missing argument 4 for recursiveGlob(

Comment: You forgot to replace the last line that call recursiveGlob by what I gave you. Add `$array` parameter to it at the end. `recursiveGlob('C:\wamp\www\scanner\scanner', 'png', 'js');` -> `recursiveGlob('C:\wamp\www\scanner\scanner', 'png', 'js', $array);`

Comment: I have added that as you said, edited my code in question as per your answer

Comment: Oh yeah, you've to replace it in your recursive function too by the way. In the first foreach loop. Sorry didn't think about it.

Comment: Yes, also Please can you help me fetching this in a variable outside the function. i.e   recursiveGlob('C:\wamp\www\scanner\scanner', 'png', 'js', $array); , can I get this in a variable eg: $result = recursiveGlob('C:\wamp\www\scanner\scanner', 'png', 'js', $array);

Comment: hey, am waiting for your answer

Comment: Hey could you wait please ? I edited my answer to add a solution that return an array as you want, give a look at `array_merge` if needed

Comment: Again geeting a warning:  Undefined variable: array_file

Comment: Edited again, it should be ok now. I gave you hints more than very exact codes, you should be able to find out what the error was given the warning. ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php
  $iterator = new DirectoryIterator("folder name");
  foreach ($iterator as $fileinfo) {


   if ($fileinfo->isFile()) {
        if ($fileinfo->getExtension() == "jpg" || $fileinfo->getExtension() == "js"){
       echo $fileinfo->getBasename('.'.$fileinfo->getExtension())."<br>";
       }
     }
}
?>
```